# Updating dynamically created input using dialog()

Tags: jquery, dynamic, clone, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am dynamically adding rows to a table by cloning a row. One cell 
has an input element.  When the row is cloned, the ID value for the input element is changed to be unique, however all inputs have the same class.  I have a click function assigned to the class assigned to the input element that opens a jQuery modal dialog().  The dialog() has a textarea where the user enters a comment.
**When the user clicks on "Accept" in the  dialog(), I want the value of the dialog's textarea element to written to the value of the input element that was clicked.**

This only works when clicking on the first, original input element.  Adding rows and clicking on the input elements opens the dialog() but the input element is not updated.

*One strange behavor does occur...*
After adding rows using the "Add row" button, if you change the 
original row's input element, all the input elements are changed to that text.
(Note: I did not include the datepicker code)

It must be IE7 compatible. ( I know it is OLD!)

I am using the following jquery scripts: (jquery-1.8.2.js) and (jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js)

Here us the simplified HTML:

```
<form id="frmTask">
<div id="popupDialog" title="Enter your comments for this IDPM Task here.">
    <p>
<div>characters left: <span id="txt-length-left"></span></div>
<textarea cols="50" rows="30" name="CommentsDialog" id="CommentsDialog" class="txtComments"></textarea>
</p>
</div>
<table style="" id="tblInput" border="0" name="tblInput" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" summary="Formatting table for output display">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col"><div width="24px">&nbsp;</div></th>
<th scope="col">Suspense Date</th>
<th scope="col">Comments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="tdTop">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="tdTop"><input name="SuspenseDate1" id="SuspenseDate1" value="" class="DatePick" /></td>
<td class="tdTop"><input cols="25" rows="1" name="Comments1" id="Comments1" class="popComments"></input></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button id="AddNew">Add Row</button>
</form>
```

Here is the code:

```
 // Copy/Clone the last row and append it to the TABLE ID referenced in the function call
    $("#AddNew").click(function() {
    addTableRow("#tblInput");
    }); 

    function addTableRow(table) {
                                                //$('input.DatePick').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    var tbody = $(table + ' tbody');
    var rows = tbody.find('tr').length;
    var newRow = tbody.find('tr:first').clone(true).appendTo(tbody);
    newRow.find(':input').val('').each(function() {
    var id = this.id
    if (id) {
    this.id = this.id.split('_')[0] + '_' + rows;
    }
    }).end().find('.DatePick').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    // set variable to the last row in the table    
    newRow = $(table + ' tr:last');
    // Remove the delete icon from the previous row before creating the new row.
    $('a.remove').remove();
    // insert a remove link in the last cell
    $('td:first-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove" alt="Delete This Row" title="Delete This Row"><img src="/images/Delete_Icon_48x48.jpg" height="24px" width="24px" border="0"><\/a>');
    var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    return true;
    }
```

Here is the modal dialog code:

```
    var inputID;
    $('.popComments').on('click', function(event) {
    inputID = event.target.id;
    alert(event.target.id + ' <- event.target.id : inputID -> ' + inputID);          
    $("#popupDialog").data("id", inputID);
    var $stuff = "Comments1";
    $('#popupDialog').dialog('open');
    $('textarea.txtComments').text("");
    });          
    // This is the popUp dialog for entering user Comments
    $("#popupDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width:"600",
    position:{ my: "top", at: "top", of: "#Comments1" },
    buttons: {
    'Cancel': function() {
    $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'Accept': function() {
    var helpMe  = $("#popupDialog").data("id");
    var txtComments = $(this).find('textarea.txtComments').val();
    $('#frmTask input#' + helpMe).val(txtComments);
    $(this).dialog('close');
    }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Manic, I think you're jumping through a few unnecessary hoops here.

- Avoid ids - they are generally unnecessary when duplicating table rows, even when complex event handling is involved.
- Hard code a remove button in your original prototype row and style it `display:none` in your style sheet.

Then, the javascript will simplify as follows:

```
$("#AddNew").on('click', function() {
    var tbody = $('#tblInput tbody');
    var newRow = tbody.find('tr').eq(0).clone(true).appendTo(tbody);
    newRow.find('input').val('').end().find('.DatePick').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    tbody.find('a.remove').hide().filter(":last").show();
});
```

You will need to modify your dialog code to work without input ids, but that shouldn't be a problem. You just need to keep a reference to the "active" input element in javascript when the dialog is opened, such that the text can be put back in the right place. This is actually simpler and more economical than remembering an id then using it to rediscover the correct input element in the DOM (which is presumably what you currently do).

If you still have a problem with the dialog etc, then edit your question to include the code and I'll have a look at it.

### EDIT:

Here's some code for handling comments, avoiding the need for input field id's:

```
var $$ = {}; //cache of reusable jQuery objects
$$.popComments = $('.popComments');
$$.popupDialog = $('#popupDialog');
$$.popupComments = $popupDialog.find('textarea.txtComments');
$$.activeInput = null;

$$.popComments.on('click', function() {
    $$.activeInput = $(this);
    $$.popupComments.empty();
    $$.popupDialog.dialog('open');
});
// This is the popUp dialog for entering user Comments
$$.popupDialog.dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "600",
    position:{ my: "top", at: "top", of: "#Comments1" },
    buttons: {
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Accept': function() {
            $$.activeInput.val( $$.popupComments.val() );
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Notes:

- untested.
- it is economical of processing power not to rediscover elements in the DOM every time they need to be addressed. The `$$` cache helps here, and saves clogging up the main `$.function(){...}` namespace by acting as an inner namespace of its own.
- presumably the dialog is already working so I've not checked the `.dialog()` options (other than the 'Accept' function).

Comment: Thanks Beetroot for the succinct code. I will change mine to match. I just realized I left out the code for the modal dialog so I have edit my original.  My biggest issue at this time is the dialog().

Comment: Beetroot, this works great! The jQuery object cache is something for me to study. I did have to change one line as I was getting an error that "$popupDialog" was undefined. I commented out that line and added a more basic reference. I am new to jQuery so it was my best choice and it works. Original code commented out: `//$$.popupComments = $popupDialog.find('textarea.txtComments');` Here is my replacement: `$$.popupComments = $("#popupDialog").find("textarea.txtComments");`

Comment: That's great. My mistake ... your version is fine (well worked out) but my version should have been `$$.popupComments = $$.popupDialog.find('textarea.txtComments');`. This is slightly more efficient as `$('#popupDialog')` doesn't need to be rediscovered.